# MacOS Mojave Boot Camp: Your Disk Could Not Be Partitioned

Tags: macos, bootcamp, error, mojave

Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

I have tried reinstalling Mojave, running First Aid, going into single user mode and typing in a command, probably everything I could find a tutorial on how to fix this issue. I just don't know what is going on, I don't care about what is making it do this, I just care about fixing it and that's all

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have fixed this problem, but i have another problem now, should i make a new question? Or should i just say it here?

Comment: Generally, you should not change a question significantly once posted. If the new question is different enough, then you should post a new question. As for this question, you can either post your own answer or delete the question entirely. If you post your own answer, but sure to return later and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @TheCreatorOfPC You know you can update your answer to explain how to fix the problem so other users can learn from your issue if they have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Just found out why it wasnt working, there was partition called “Free Space” in Macintosh HD i removed that but now i have a new problem, im gonna search up how to fix it, and if none of it works, im gonna make a new question